JNI: Generated file name and functions are cumbersome
I decided to put my Java "native"-methods class in some package within my program.
When I call javac -h on that java class, it generates a file named com_example_foo_baz_MyJniInterface.h
The same applies to that auto-generated functions inside the header file.
I know it's a default behaviour that probably supposed to ensure uniqueness, but is there a way to generate the file without this cumbersome prefix?
Thanks!
EDIT:
if the file is not going to change too often (or at all) is there a point to stick with the auto-generation option? Instead, I can edit the file once and that's it.

As specified in documentation and as you correctly supposed, the native methods name in the header file is build to obtain unicity, and to let the vm link correctly the java and the C counterpart at runtime.
Anyway, the name of the generated header file has nothing to do with uniqueness of methods, and may be changed after the creation; in the javac command documentation there is no option to force the output file, at most you can tell the command the directory where to place the .h file.
For the contents of the headers file, since it is autogenerated, I suggest not to edit them; consider that the .c file that will implement the methods in .h would be a proxy to some real implementations that may be implemented in C or C++ (and those would have less fancy names).

Thanks for the information, but when I think about it, why would it matter at all? (the functions names)

Because the native compiled artifiact is a library (a .dll or a .so), and the function names are the "entry points" of that library, so that the JVM knows what to run when is called a native method in the java execution. It's a convention: JVM searches in the library an entry point called with the concatenation of the package, class name and native method that declares it. It's similar to WSDL and SOAP messaging, there must be a fitting between the "caller" and the "called": unfortunately, in JNI there aren't annotations that may customize the names of methods, parameters, etc.

If your app can run on JDK 22, consider using Oracle's replacement for JNI.

The Foreign Function and Memory (FFM) API enables Java programs to
interoperate with code and data outside the Java runtime. This API
enables Java programs to call native libraries and process native data
without the brittleness and danger of JNI. The API invokes foreign
functions, code outside the JVM, and safely accesses foreign memory,
memory not managed by the JVM.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/core/foreign-function-and-memory-api.html
More info from Baeldung:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-foreign-memory-access
